# Can't retrieve array keys in foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have cycled through arrays hundreds of times, but I must be going crazy today, because I am getting undesired results.

I have stored all information in my $data variable in which the print_r shows the following

```
Array
(
[side_orders] => Array
    (
        [white_rice] => Array
            (
                [price] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0.50
                    )
            )
    )

[soup] => Array
    (
        [wonton_soup] => Array
            (
                [price] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => (pt)2.00
                        [1] => (qt)3.75
                    )
            )
    )

[steamed_dishes] => Array
    (
        [vegetarian] => Array
            (
                [info] => snow_peas
                [price] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 4.95
                    )
             )
     )

   )
```

I am trying to display 'side_orders,soup,steamed_dishes'

so I then use the following to test it out.

```
             foreach($data as $dat)
             {
                 echo key($data);
             }
```

Which returns 'side_ordersside_ordersside_orders'

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're doing `as $dat` then do `echo key($dat);` and not `$data`.

Comment: Or just do `foreach($data as $key => $dat)`

Comment: @JohnConde OP's on their way now... and I'm off to lah-lah land. ciao! I'll let you take over ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- that makes two of us :)

Comment: @JohnConde A presto, buona notte.

Comment: @Fred Doing that just results in the first item of each array being shown. For example 'white_ricewonton_soupvegetarian'. Even if each of the side_orders,soup, steamed_dishes has multiple items, it will still show only 3 items total.

Comment: Okay, I got it using $data as $key => $value and echoing $key without the key() function. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array=array(
"side_orders" => 
array("white_rice" => 
array("price" => array("0" => "0.50"))
),
"soup" => 
array("wonton_soup" =>
array("price" => array("0" => "(pt)2.00", "1" => "(qt)3.75")))
);
///// Display Array /////
print_r($array);
////////////////////////
$side_orders_price_0 = $array['side_orders']['white_rice']['price']['0'];
$soup_price_0 = $array['soup']['wonton_soup']['price']['0'];
$soup_price_1 = $array['soup']['wonton_soup']['price']['1'];

echo '</br>(side_orders -> white_rice -> price -> 0) = '.$side_orders_price_0.' </br>';
echo '(soup -> wonton_soup -> price -> 0) = '.$soup_price_0.' </br>';
echo '(soup -> wonton_soup -> price -> 1) = '.$soup_price_1.' </br>';
?>
```